# Netbeans, how to delete a Gradle project

Tags: netbeans

I have a working Gradle project in Netbeans and I'd like to use the same sources in another Netbeans project.

Unfortunately it's forbidden to use the same sources in multiple projects, so I'd like to remove this Gradle project from Netbeans.

The existing answers are not valid because they refer non-gradle projects.

I tried to delete the cache but it didn't work.

I tried also to delete the user configuration directory `C:\Users\gbarbieri\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\12.0\config` but then I don't have anymore the option to create a project from existing sources (and all the others ones are gone as well).

How shall I do?

Spec:
Netbeans 12

Comment: Can't you just use the "original" project as a (library) dependency in your second project?

Comment: No, I basically want to have a non-gradle version of the same project because of compiling performances

Answer (score 0):

I ended up uninstalling and reinstalling Netbeans and it worked

Answer (score 0):

I deleted the project from the system folder and they automatically stopped showing on Netbeans.